# Connect to redis with coffeescript with connection string (host,pass, instance)

Tags: coffeescript, redis, connection

```
connection = 'redis://redis:1234@mydevserver.dev/5'
```

I have such connection string : I need to connect to redis on mydevserver.dev with 5 instance with password "1234"

```
client = redis.createClient()
```

If I will create client like this it will try to connect to redis server with default parameters

How can I connect with my connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like node_redis doesn't support [connection settings](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#rediscreateclient) in URL format. So, try to pass connection settings as recommended in documentation.